# How to identify the NonPagedPool Start Memory address from a memory dump

Tags: windows, memory, dump

I need to find the memory address where starts the NonPagedPool. I saw some people doing it with Rekall, but I'm having a lot of problems with it.

Is that possible with Volatility ?

Tks